# Code validation in minted package? How to disable it?

Tags: listings, minted, code, sourcecode, syntax-highlighting

I'm using minted for inserting syntax highlighted HTML code in my document. But it isn't simple HTML (valid HTML I mean) and has some special characters and definitions (if you're interested, it's Angular template code)

For example, consider this snippet which is a valid HTML (in my case):

```
<div class="mode" [ngClass]="{'hidden': x.id == y.id}" *ngIf="z == m"></div>
```

Here is the result of `\inputminted{html}{....path of file....}`:
[image: Result]

As you see, the invalid characters in HTML (`[`, `]`, `.`, `{,` }` and others) have a red frame.

Is there any way to disable this feature and remove these ugly frames?

Comment: if that is a known templating language to pygments you can specify that instead of html (eg php etc, see the list here) http://pygments.org/docs/lexers  otherwise (but not as good) just redefine `\PYG@tok@err` not to be a red box

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Unfortunately there isn't yet a lexer for my case. How to redefine `\PYG@tok@err`? (sorry I'm a bit new to tex)

Comment: the `Angular2Lexer` lexer no good?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Sorry I didn't check it, but as you mention in the answer, it isn't complete.

Comment: actually i suspect i should have used `html+ng2` rather than `ng2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Angular2 lexer `ng2` or define the default error styling to just do nothing rather than be a red box.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}

\begin{minted}{html}
  <div class="mode" [ngClass]="{'hidden': x.id == y.id}" *ngIf="z == m"></div>
\end{minted}


\begin{minted}{ng2}
  <div class="mode" [ngClass]="{'hidden': x.id == y.id}" *ngIf="z == m"></div>
\end{minted}


\makeatletter
\expandafter\def\csname PYGdefault@tok@err\endcsname{\def\PYGdefault@bc##1{##1}}
\makeatother
\begin{minted}{html}
  <div class="mode" [ngClass]="{'hidden': x.id == y.id}" *ngIf="z == m"></div>
\end{minted}


\end{document}
```

Comment: The third option (redefinition) doesn't work, the frames are still visible.

Comment: @jiun it produces the output that I show, with no red boxes, what do you mean by visible frames?

Comment: the red boxes are present. It's a bit weird, but if I copy/paste your code in a new document, its result is like yours (no boxes at third solution) but in my current document which consist of multiple files and uses sigconf/acmart document class it doesn't work.

Comment: I got it, it's because of using a style (`bw`), after commenting out `\usemintedstyle{bw}` it works as expected. What's wrong? I have put the `\makeatletter....` after `\usemintedstyle` command.

Comment: One more question, should I put `\makeatletter, \makeatother` before every `\begin{minted}` commands? Or it is a global configuration?

Comment: @jiun you should be able to do it in the preamble after any other minted settings, if the style defines a format for error tokens you probably need to redefine a style  specific command rather than the default one, just look in the files in the _minted cache directory for "err" and find the command name, that;s all i did here

Comment: Thanks, it was `\makeatletter\expandafter\def\csname PYGbw@tok@err\endcsname{\def\PYGbw@bc##1{##1}}\makeatother`. (`bw` instead of `default`)