# Using special Characters with minted + Haskell

Tags: minted

I want to use a special character(U+2225) with minted for Haskell syntax:

```
\begin{document} 
$\parallel$ this works as expected

\begin{minted}{haskell}
regardless which method I use in here I cannot get the paralell symbol to accure...
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

I allso experimentated with \DeclareUnicodeCharacter but couldn't get it to work...
Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: Does your mono font have that character (you can check with the `albatross` tool)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not entirely clear what your experiments with `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` have been so far, but the following works with `pdflatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2225}{$\parallel$}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document} 
$\parallel$ this works as expected

\begin{minted}{haskell}
parseOr :: Parser Operator
parseOr = Or <$> oneOf "v+∥"
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

When you use ∥ outside of a string `minted` thinks that there is a syntax error and will display a red box around the character. You can switch this off by escaping to LaTeX before you print the symbol:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2225}{$\parallel$}
\begin{document} 
$\parallel$ this works as expected

\begin{minted}[escapeinside=\#\#]{haskell}
parseOr :: Parser Operator
parseOr = Or <$> oneOf "v+∥"

doSomething = doFirst #∥# doSecond
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

The problem here is that you need to find a character that you don't use anywhere in your code *and* that is allowed for `escapeinside` (basically only standard ASCII).

An alternative is to switch off the error boxes altogether:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2225}{$\parallel$}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginEnvironment{minted}{\dontdofcolorbox}
\def\dontdofcolorbox{\renewcommand\fcolorbox[4][]{##4}}
\makeatother
\begin{document} 
$\parallel$ this works as expected

\begin{minted}{haskell}
parseOr :: Parser Operator
parseOr = Or <$> oneOf "v+∥"

doSomething = doFirst ∥ doSecond
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

Result in both cases:

[image]

Source: [Minted red box around greek characters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/343494/minted-red-box-around-greek-characters).

Comment: this is working - but now the ∥ is surrounded with a red square

Comment: that is probably because it is not allowed in Haskell at that position - or it is allowed but Minted thinks it is not. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/343494/minted-red-box-around-greek-characters or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/424421/code-validation-in-minted-package-how-to-disable-it for example. I will make an edit to this post as well.